# How to fetch data through jsons?

Tags: android

I want to know that how can i fetch data through j sons. I.I am creating like this but did not get any data?

```
"arr": [1]
0:  {
"obj": {
"id": "24"
"dispensary_id": "24"
"item_name": "item 3"
"total_feedback": "1"
"total_item": "13"
"followers": "7"
"follow_status": "following"
"category": "Edibles"
"strain": "Indica"
"tch": "0.70"
"cbd": "13.30"
"description": "testing items"
"image": "1447508911_greenfeed-3.jpg"
"qty1": "1/8 OZ"
"price1": "100"
"qty2": "1/4 OZ"
"price2": "200"
"qty3": "1/2 OZ"
"price3": "400"
"qty4": "1 OZ"
"price4": "799"
"dispensary_first_name": "Acme Dispensary"
"dispensary_last_name": "Smith"
"company": "Acme Dispensary"
"dispensary_image": "1449182412.png"
"city": "Irvine"
"state": "CA"
"status": "1"
}-
}-
-
"result": "true"
}
```

Comment: Where is your code for fetching data?

Comment: your JSON is invalid

Comment: but when i saw in postman this was like this:-

Comment: ///////////////////////

Comment: {
  "arr": [
    {
      "obj": {
        "id": "24",
        "dispensary_id": "24",
        "item_name": "GrasshopperCooky",
        "total_feedback": "1",
        "total_item": "13",
        "followers": "7",
        "follow_status": "following",
        "category": "Edibles",
        "strain": "Hybrid",
        "tch": "0.90",
        "cbd": "1.10",
        "description": "testing....",
        "image": "1447508928_greenfeed-2.jpg",

Comment: @NirajKumar [see here](http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/)

Comment: and one more soultion:

Comment: i have to view image according to value:- for example if i got jsons value like this:---- "strain":"1" if "1" then i have to shoe image combo in view 1,if got "2" the show image combo 2 in view 1 like this how can i do ...

Comment: see here [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) ,, may be its help you

Comment: no i knew that which you gave me the link

Comment: i simply do that if get value like "1" the show image1 and if "2" the show image 2

Answer (score 0):

Use gson library for parsing JSON data. To learn how to use it go through with this link http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

your JOSN format is wrong it should be like this

```
{
    "obj": {
        "id": "24",
        "dispensary_id": "24",
        "item_name": "item 3",
        "total_feedback": "1",
        "total_item": "13",
        "followers": "7",
        "follow_status": "following",
        "category": "Edibles",
        "strain": "Indica",
        "tch": "0.70",
        "cbd": "13.30",
        "description": "testing items",
        "image": "1447508911_greenfeed-3.jpg",
        "qty1": "1/8 OZ",
        "price1": "100",
        "qty2": "1/4 OZ",
        "price2": "200",
        "qty3": "1/2 OZ",
        "price3": "400",
        "qty4": "1 OZ",
        "price4": "799",
        "dispensary_first_name": "Acme Dispensary",
        "dispensary_last_name": "Smith",
        "company": "Acme Dispensary",
        "dispensary_image": "1449182412.png",
        "city": "Irvine",
        "state": "CA",
        "status": "1"
    }
}
```

for this you can check on whether your json is valid or not http://jsonlint.com/

for creating json you can use some library like

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.add("key", "value");
jsonObject.add("key", "value");
```